# Programa de consola con python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.7

soy nuevo en la comunidad y estoy realizando un curso de python, el profesor me ha pedido un programa de consola en python que permita saber la cantidad de meses transcurridos desde mi fecha de naciemiento hasta la fecha actual.
Se que tengo que importar las librerias :

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
```

Pero no encuentro como realizar la operacion para realizar el calculo de los meses, si alguien pudiera explicarme se los agradeceria.

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, es muy importante revisar [ask], saludos

Answer (score 0):

quizás esto te pueda ayudar

```html
end_date = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)
start_date = datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 1)

num_months = (end_date.year - start_date.year) * 12 + (end_date.month - start_date.month)

print(num_months)
```

Comment: Gracia por tu contribución, ¿podrías explicarnos que es lo que realiza o como solucionaría el problema planteado en la pregunta?, revisar [answer],saludos.